# Update Mongodb collection record without retaining fields that not on the new record

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way in Mongodb to update a record and drop fields that doesn't exist in updated version?

Like an existing record is:

```
{
   "id": "helloworld",
   "icon": "globe",
   "title": "Hello World!",
}
```

When updated with this it looks like it did not update because it's not dropping "icon".

```
{
   "id": "helloworld",
   "title": "Hello World!",
}
```

The only option that I can think of is deleting the record and insert it again or figure out the fields that doesn't exist and use $unset.

I just want to find out if there's a better way to do what I want in Mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update method can also completely replace a document if the update document only contains field:value pairs (instead of using update operators such as $set)

For an example,

```
> db.world.insert( {
   "id": "helloworld",
   "icon": "globe",
   "title": "Hello World!",
  } )

> db.world.update( 
     { id: "helloworld" }, 
     { "id": "helloworld", title: "Hello World!" }
)

> db.world.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5320e93b80b181227adb0e24"), 
   "id" : "helloworld",
   "title" : "Hello World!"
}
```

For another example, you can also see

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#example-update-replace-fields

Hope this helps

Comment: You are correct. My update issue is not caused by Mongodb. It's caused by other part of the app where the fields are not getting dropped. Thank you for clarifying this feature.